# How to find all possible combinations with repetitions without duplicates?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I need to find all possible combinations taking k out of n numbers with repetitive, without duplicates.
For example of numbers '[1, 2, 3]' with taking 2 result should be

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 3
2 2
3 3
```

When I call the main function combs I only declare array `arr = [ 1 3 5 ] n = 3(size of arr) r = 2`
I get:"**Out of memory. The likely cause is an infinite recursion within the program.**":

```
function combs(arr, n, r)
chosen = zeros(1, r+1, 'int8');
repeat(chosen, arr, 1, r, 1, n);
end

function repeat(chosen, arr, index, r, start, ends)
    if(index == r)
        for i = 1:r
           arr(chosen(i))
        end
    end
    for i = start:ends
        chosen(index) = i;
        repeat(chosen, arr, index, r, i, ends)
    end
end
```

Comment: What errors do you get? That's perfectly legal MATLAB syntax (assuming `r`, `i` and `index` are assigned).

Comment: Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Comment: Please add this information to your question using [edit] and include the values for the 3 variables you're using. We can't reproduce your problem without a [mre].

Comment: Your first error is that array indices in MATLAB are 1-based (indices go from 1..n rather than 0..n-1) and you're passing an `index` of 0. I don't think you intended to create a 2-dimensional array for `chosen`, either. You may have meant `chosen = zeros(1, r+1, 'int8');` to get a 1-dimensional array. I did not debug further.

Comment: I already fixed those error, but now I get: `Out of memory. The likely cause is an infinite recursion within the program.` @beaker

Comment: *How* did you fix it? Again, unless we can see the code you're using, we can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: `repeat` calls itself with exactly the same parameters it was called with. That of course leads to infinite recursion. What is the purpose of the code? What are you trying to do here? It makes no sense whatsoever. And given the comments and edits so far, I would recommend that you start with a tutorial on basic MATLAB syntax. Guessing at syntax is a painful way to learn a new language. For example try this: https://matlabacademy.mathworks.com/

Comment: It looks like you left out the `index + 1` in the recursive call to `repeat`.

Comment: @beaker I did not, I fixed it as well as going `0...n-1` to going `1..n`

Comment: @CrisLuengo you are wrong, `i`is variable that changes in repeat: `chosen(index) = i;` each time it calls itself with different `i`

Comment: @GoodnightJess Then why did your previous version call it with `index + 1`? Why does the C# version call it with `index + 1`? That changes the value used in the *recursive* call. Changing `i` only changes each iteration.

Comment: `index` never changes, so in the first iteration of the loop you write the same value to the same location then call the same function which will repeat this operation. You maybe intend to loop over `start+1:ends`? I don’t know what the code is meant to do, so can’t say how to fix it.

Comment: Also, the contents of `chosen` doesn’t affect the iterative behavior of the function. The value of `start` is important, and that one is always the same, you never get to a second iteration of the for loop.